# Looped counter after 24 hour base on timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

That's the code I use for the counter, so it will repeat (loop) after 24 hours.

I found on [Github](https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/issues/55).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(function(){
        var nextDay = new Date(). setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        $('#clock').countdown(nextDay, function(event) {
          $(this).html(event.strftime(''
                + '<div><span class="number">%D</span> <span class="timertext">days</span></div>'
                + '<div><span class="number">%H</span> <span class="timertext">hours</span></div>'
                + '<div><span class="number">%M</span> <span class="timertext">mins</span></div>'
                + '<div><span class="number">%S</span> <span class="timertext">secs</span></div>'
            ));
        });
    });
});
```

Try this `var nextYear = moment.tz("2018-30-12 00:00", "US/Central");` it's working fine, not sure how to use on `var nextDay = new Date(). setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`.

I want the counter to appear with a specific timezone. For example, US/Central. I use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Answer (score 0):

```
//offset would be how many hours off from UTC, e.g CST = -6, GMT/UTC = 0
var offset = -6;
var coun = true;

//Below is a looper every second.
setInterval(newDay, 100);
function newDay(){
  var d = new Date();      
  var curTime = (d.getUTCHours() + offset)+""+d.getUTCMinutes();
  if((curTime == "0000") && (coun == true)){
    //Insert javascript needed here
    coun = false;
    //the above variable stops the inserted javascript repeating.
  }
  else if(curTime != "0000"){
    coun = true;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: just in script tags. I presume this is for a html site. <script></script>

Comment: I put the script above my script, but the counter did’t match UTC -06:00. What wrong?

Comment: I just change it to getUTCHours. My mistake. I forgot to add that part